# How can you achieve vi's `se ai` in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

What's the simplest way to set up auto indentation in Emacs? I can see that auto-fill correctly wraps, say:

```
  This is an indented block, and the
  wrapping happens as expected.
```

On the other hand, I get this unwanted behavior:

```
  This is an indented short line.
I'm now taken to the beginning of the
line.  I expected to be under the "T".
```

In other words, how can I get the equivalent of vi's `se ai` in Emacs?

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation

Comment: it is mode dependant. What type of file do you want indented? Each mode will typically have its own indent variables. One might also want to address tabs vs. spaces.

Comment: jordanm, your link does it for me (I'm disappointed at the verbosity required if you don't want to press C-J instead of RET...). Feel free to leave an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, bdowning. I was hoping for something even in fundamental mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comments as an answer so this question has a formal answer...

The short answer is that for a buffer in "fundamental mode", run `M-x electric-indent-mode`

Emacs is modal, and each mode selects the kind of auto-indentation that is appropriate for that mode. For example, if you edit a text file, you will be in "text mode" and lines will by default automatically respect indentation of a prior line.

When Emacs doesn't find a special a mode for the buffer you are editing, it defaults to something called "Fundamental Mode". The document string for this is:

```
Major mode not specialized for anything in particular.
Other major modes are defined by comparison with this one.
```

The way many modes handle auto-indentation is to use a minor mode called 
"electic-indent-mode" (A minor mode is a variation added to a major mode like "fundamental mode").

Finally, as indicated in the comments, [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentation) has more information on indentation.

Comment: Thanks! It's been indeed a while since I asked the question, and you have provided a solid and thorough answer. Cheers.